# Create a tooltip on a node - treepanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'd like to create a tooltip when I'm hovering a node on a treepanel, then look through the tree at this node in order to count its leaves and then show the result in the tooltip. At this moment, I **can't** catch the id of the node, just got the id of the treepanel. (the listeners are part of the treepanel)

```
listeners: {
        afterrender: function( value, eOpts ) {
            Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                target: value.getEl(),
                listeners: {
                    beforeshow: function (value, eOpts ) {
                        treepanel.getRootNode().cascadeBy(function (node) {
                            // if (node == 

                        });
                        view.getEl();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to catch the id of the leaf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the root of the problem is how to display the tooltip then the easies way is to get a reference to the node and then calling:

```
node.set('qtip', 'The tip text')
```

You don't need to go down to the DOM to get element for manually created tooltip target.

Comment: what's the event to catch the node wanted?

Comment: Well, you can even deliver `qtip:'Something'` as a part of your tree dataset or static tree data, then you don't need the call at all. Otherwise it depends on what the user is doing: click, mouseover, it depends...

Comment: @Saki, when I set qtip as you suggested, it works when it is a static string, but wont when it is a dynamic string like `object.qtip = a+" - "+b;` I am suing 3.4 version